# How to mock interface method to return the parameter value using closures

Tags: closures, phpunit

Sometimes it happens that we need to mock some method of the interface just to work and we do not really care what it will return, we just need to ensure it is called.

There is an approach to set

```
->expects(static::once())->method('someMethod')->willReturn('dumbValue');
```

But it is often necessary to see in the test with which parameter it was called, then we need to use

```
->expects(static::once())->method('someMethod')->with(static::equalTo('paramvalue'))->willReturn('dumbValue');
```

It gets longer and longer.

Is there an approach to return the parameter value that is given to the function mocked in willReturn() method?
It would be so simple to test the output with data provider then

Answer (score 0):

We can use closures to process the callback.

```
    $this->translator                   = $this->createMock(TranslatorInterface::class);
    $this->translator->method('translate')->will(
        $this->returnCallback(
            function ($msgid) {
                return (string)$msgid;
            }
        )
    );
```

Also, we can return not only parameter value but any variable value, generated before:

```
        $variable = 'hello'
        $this->returnCallback(
            function ($msgid) use $variable {
                return $msgid . $variable;
            }
        )
```

and the assert will look like:

```
    static::assertEquals(
        'key',
        $this->translator->translate('key');
    );


    static::assertEquals(
        'some text and translated '. 'key',
        'some text and translated ' . $this->translator->translate('key');
    );
```